# django-crispy-forms have field and button on same row

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am needing to have a bootstrap PrependedText field with a button on the same row. I can get it on the same row but it shows the button before the textbox and I want it after. What am I doing wrong and how do I get it to display after the box (on the right side of the text field)

```
serial = forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off',}))
    serial.label = ''

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.form_action = 'checkout'
    helper.form_method = 'post'

    helper.layout = Layout(
        HTML("<p class='alert-info'>Please scan the items barcode or enter the serial # in the field below.</p>"),
        Div(
            Div(PrependedText('serial', 'Serial #',css_class='input-xlarge'), css_class='span1'),
            Div(Submit('submit','Submit', css_class='btn-primary'), css_class='span1'),
            css_class='row-fluid'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I noticed that in your definition of the `serial` field, you forgot to put `widget=` before `forms.TextInput(`. Also, your `p` should have the `alert` class too, not just `alert-info`.

I was able to kind of fix the problem by changing the first instance of `span1` to `span6`, but I definitely don't recommend that because resizing the window causes layout issues and can even make it appear that there is no submit button at all!

I was going to recommend using `PrependedAppendedText`, but [the template](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap/layout/appended_prepended_text.html) makes the assumption that you're appending text and not a button, so that won't work unless you override the template (e.g. `PrependedAppendedText.template = 'custom_appended_prepended_text.html'`). If you want to go that route, just copy the original template to your custom one, remove the `span` that the second instance of `{{ crispy_appended_text|safe }}` is inside of, and then use code like this:

```
Div(PrependedAppendedText('serial', 'Serial #', '<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>', css_class='input-xlarge'), css_class='span1'),
```

I do have another suggestion, though. I like this solution much better, but it means giving up the prepended text in favor of placeholder text. First, in addition to setting the field's `autocomplete` attribute to `off`, set its `class` attribute to `input-xlarge` and its `placeholder` attribute to `Serial #`. Next, use this code:

```
FieldWithButtons('serial', StrictButton('Submit', type='submit', css_class='btn-primary')),
```

No need to create a custom template. Also, between the `p` you have at the top of the form and the field's placeholder text, I don't think your users will be confused by the lack of prepended text.

Comment: +1 for helping with the alert class and the above and beyond solutions. I will try them and get back. I tried adding a `StrictButton` into the `PrependedAppendedText` but it just showed a blank area. I will try just including the HTML instead.

Comment: If doing the first solution how would I make the template so I can deploy it to heroku? Right now it seems like I have to edit the package to create a new template.

Comment: @Bot It's just a template, so you can put it wherever you want as long as you have a template loader that can find it. No need to modify django-crispy-forms.